# If you miss that train then you'll have to get a taxi

Tags: commas

Some dictionary said, 'If you miss that train then you'll have to get a taxi.' Is it wrong not to use a comma  between an if-clause and a main clause? I'm confused because this is from an Oxford dictionary.

Comment: No, it isn't wrong. The sentence is short and simple enough for the meaning to be clear without needing a comma to separate the clauses.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Love you

Answer (score -1):

If a conditional clause comes before the main clause, a comma is used.

Examples from Cambridge Dictionary (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals):
*If you see Dora, will you give her a message?* (conditional clause first; a comma is normally used in writing)
*I’ll go to Bristol tomorrow if the weather is good*. (conditional clause second; a comma is not normally used in writing)